# Can't build Visual Studio Code source - "Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-bom'"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to build Visual Studio Code so the dependencies are compiled in (can't install rpm packages as I don't have root).  I have worked through a few issues so far, but I can't figure out why I am getting the following error.

```
[mrhicks@xxxxxx repo]$ yarn run watch
yarn run v1.12.3
$ gulp watch --max_old_space_size=4095
[20:28:22] Node flags detected: --max_old_space_size=4095
[20:28:22] Respawned to PID: 27503
module.js:550
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'gulp-bom'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:548:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:475:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/users/mrhicks/projects/vscode/repo/build/lib/compilation.js:10:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I have make sure to re-run `sudo npm install` to try and ensure everything for npm is installed.  I have been following the instructions from the VSCode site [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#build-and-run)

Answer (score 3):

I had this locally. It went away after `yarn add gulp-bom --no-save`. ‍♂️

If you applied the changes at https://github.com/addaleax/natives/commit/0abbec6b0e211c6bbe3bf0d2b33fcd68f5a6c980, you'll need to re-apply them after.

Comment: For me it's not working. after installing gulp-bom it says Cannot find module 'gulp-uglify'. If I install 'gulp-uglify' it says Cannot find module 'gulp-bom' and so on...